# Ethernet Network Switch MAC address

Tags: ethernet, network

I want to learn about the RSTP,STP supported network switches.

As I know, the BPDU frames have 802.3 Frame Structure.
[image]

For example switch have aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:00 base MAC address.

When I check the some BPDU frames on the port 2 of the Network Switches (3COM RSTP supported switches) with the Wireshark networkanalyse programs, BPDU have like this frame:

DA: 01:80:c1:00:00:00 (BPDU specific address)

SA: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:02 ( Although switch MAC address is aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:00, than BPDU have port information end of the MAC address 00+02 = 02)

Besides that I know that, switches save the other device in ALU table ( Address Lookup Table) by looking Source Address (SA). So How are these things handled by RSTP switches?

If RSTP switch looks the Source Address any incomming frame, its ALU table have many MAC address with other device's port MAC address and other devices base MAC address. For example if there is another switch and it's baseMAC address is aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:02 , it will be problem in Network. How switches work to prevent this ? How does table saves, (or doesnt) frames like BPDU?

When I doing custom ethernet switch with http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/KSZ8563R-Data-Sheet-DS00002418B.pdf I have a problem about this subjects

Comment: MAC addresses are (supposed to be) unique.

Comment: This may be more appropriate for https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jcaron I opened the subject there but they directed me here because it is about custom ethernet switch

Comment: Every ethernet device is supposed to have a unique MAC address.  These are set at manufacture time.  Each company has their own EUI which gives them ~24million addresses to use. When they run out, they buy another block.

Comment: If there are duplicates, the network switches do not work to prevent it.  It is undefined behavior, and how it is handled is going to be implementation specific.

Comment: My question is not about the Switch MAC address, BPDU packets have Source Address assign port MAC so device send to ethernet packet frame in MAC port, so if the MAC port identical with another device, how the Rstp network switch solve this ?